# map in xslt 2.0 is not working while passing key-value from parameter?

Tags: xml, xslt, key, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am facing problem while fetch data from map: key :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="mnth" select="3"/>
            <xsl:variable name="months" select="map{ '1': 'January', '2': 'February', '3': 'March'}"/>
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="concat($apos, string($mnth), $apos)"/>
            <pos>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
            </pos>
            <correctval>
                <xsl:value-of select="$months('3')"/>
            </correctval>
            <valuenotcoming>
                <xsl:value-of select="$months($pos)"/>
            </valuenotcoming>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In below code `$pos` is returning `'3'` and acording to this `$months($pos)` which is equal to `$months('3')`, but `$months($pos)` is not returning it's corresponding values:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="concat($apos, string($mnth), $apos)"/>
 <pos><xsl:value-of select="$pos"/></pos>
 <correctval><xsl:value-of select="$months('3')"/></correctval>
 <valuenotcoming><xsl:value-of select="$months($pos)"/></valuenotcoming>
```

**Required Output:**

```
<root>
   <pos>'3'</pos>
   <correctval>March</correctval>
   <valuenotcoming>March</valuenotcoming>
</root>
```

**Current Output:**

```
<root>
   <pos>'3'</pos>
   <correctval>March</correctval>
   <valuenotcoming/>
</root>
```

Comment: There is no `map` in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: But my xslt return proper output. I think its depend on saxon version. Right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pos` contains a string of 3 characters in length; literally `'3'`.

When you do `$months('3')` the apostrophes are to indicate the use of a string literal (as opposed to a number). By the string itself is just a single character `3`.

You need to change the declaration of `$pos` to this, so that then it gets set to a string literal containing just a single character of `3`.

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="string($mnth)"/>
```

Also note, the `map` function is only available in XSLT 3.0. If you are using an XSLT 3.0 processor, like Saxon 9.8 HE, it will still process the map function even if you put `version="2.0"` in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for answer!!!!, It's working now, :). Actually i thought it was syntax of parameter within apos.

Comment: I used `<xsl:value-of select="$months(string($mnth))"/>` its fine for me. Thanks again!!!!